# ошибка qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "windows" in "" This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyside6

я использую библиотеку Pyside6, но код не хочет запускаться, и выдает ошибку

```
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "windows" in ""  
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
```

На steckoveflow уже кучу раз оговаривали эту ошибку, и как правило рекомендовали переместить папку platforms в папку с питоном, но это не помогло. Чаще всего люди сталкиваются с этой проблемой, работая c Anaconda в PyCharm, но я не использую анаконду, и программирую в Sublime Text, так что все предыдущие ответы не работают. Кто знает, что можно еще сделать?

Comment: Можно попробовать установить переменную окружения `QT_PLUGIN_PATH` чтобы она указывала на папку `plugins` (в которой и platforms расположена).

Comment: @GrAnd А где эта переменная и как ее менять?

Comment: В OC, в терминале, в программе. В зависимости от того, насколько жёстко её нужно задать. Просто [погуглите](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5+%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F).

Comment: @GrAnd Я добавил переменную окружения и указал путь, но ничего не поменялось, какие еще могут быть варианты?

Comment: Ещё можно попробовать в `QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH` указать путь уже до папки `platforms` (ну и удостовериться, что там есть qwindows.dll). Или выставлять эту переменную в самой программе в самом начале. `import os, PySide6;  
dirname = os.path.dirname(PySide6.__file__);  
plugin_path = os.path.join(dirname, 'plugins', 'platforms.x');  
os.environ['QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH'] = plugin_path;  
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *`